# How to replicate downward gravity in d3 v5 forceSimulation?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to replicate this force layout made in an older version of d3:

http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/5Yv24/

Here is some of the code I have so far:

```js
  // function gravityRight(alpha: number) {
  //   for (const n of nodes) {
  //     //@ts-ignore
  //     n.vy = n.y * alpha * -0.1;
  //   }
  // }
  const forceX = d3.forceX(width * 2).strength(0.5);

  const graphLayout = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .nodes(nodes as any)
    .force(
      "links",
      d3
        .forceLink()
        .links(links)
        .id((d: any) => d.id)
    )

    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-20))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2))
    // .force("gravity", gravityRight)
    .force("x", forceX)
    .on("tick", ticked);
```

However it is not working as I expect, my graph gets somewhat distorted, but it does not point downwards (or right for my exact purpose), any idea on how to achieve this?

[image: my graph]

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, by locking the first node somewhere in the screen, so the gravity force does not drag it with the rest of the nodes, here is the implementation:

```js
  const forceX = d3.forceX(width).strength(0.013);

  const graphLayout = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .nodes(nodes as any)
    .force(
      "links",
      d3
        .forceLink()
        .links(links)
        .strength(2)
        .id((d: any) => d.id)
    )
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
    .force("x", forceX)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  // Lock the first node in the middle of the screen
  nodes[0].fx = margin.left + 20;
  nodes[0].fy = heightMiddle;
```

[image: rightward graph]

Now my force graph is pointing rightwards, the way I wanted it :)

Comment: fixed root node actually works, thanks!